# Update list view during TimerTask with custom Adapter

Tags: java, android, notifydatasetchanged

I have created an Adapter that will populate my custom list view, the code works when I set the list right away, which I have commented out below.  My list updates every second and I have read that I need to update my Adapter along with it and that is why my list view is not updating.  The list view comes up blank because the original size of use ArrayList is empty.  None of the answers I have come across fix my code and I can't figure out how to update my list view.

I tried notifyDataSetChanged and can't get it to do anything, I left it in there so you can see how I used it.

Here is my code where the list view is set in a TimerTask and where the getDataForListView class is:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    //set variables
    public ArrayList<String> use = new ArrayList<String>(); //holds app name
    public ArrayList<Integer> useTime = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //holds app time
    //TextView sepW;  //sets text to apps being used
    //TextView sepT; // sets text to time app has been used
    Timer timers = new Timer();  //gets TimerTask to run on start
    final Handler handler = new Handler();  //used in TimerTask


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //sepW = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sepWord);
        //sepT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dude);
        timers.schedule(time, 1000,1000);
    }

    TimerTask time = new TimerTask(){

        public void run() {

            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //Makes a String of current app being used
                    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    final List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();

                    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
                    for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo process: runningProcesses) {
                        b.append(process.processName);
                        b.append(" ");
                    }

                    //splits string of apps into app names
                    String wordS = b.toString();
                    String[] apps = wordS.split("\\ ");
                    String[] separated = apps[0].split("\\.");

                    //finds if app has already been used in day and if so what the index of the app is (spot int)
                    int i = 0;
                    int spot = -1;
                    if (use.size() > 0) {
                        while (i < use.size()) {
                            if ((use.get(i)).equals(separated[2])) {
                                spot = i;
                                i = use.size();
                            }
                            i = i + 1;
                        }
                    }

                    //goes to index of app being used and adds to time
                    if (spot < 0) {
                        use.add(separated[2]);
                        useTime.add(0);
                    } else if (spot >= 0) {
                        int hold = useTime.get(spot);
                        hold=hold+1;
                        useTime.set(spot, hold);
                    }

                    final String[] useArray = use.toArray(new String[use.size()]);

                    //make list view to show data

                    //ArrayAdapter<String> appNameAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, useArray);
                    TableViewList codeAppAdapter = new TableViewList();
                    ListView appNameS = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.showData);
                    codeAppAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    appNameS.setAdapter(codeAppAdapter);

                    //**sets text to help with debug for now
                    //sepT.setText(useTime.toString());
                    //sepW.setText(use.toString());
                }

            });
        }
    };


    public List<CodeLearnApp> getDataForListView(){
        List<CodeLearnApp> codeLearnAppList = new ArrayList<CodeLearnApp>();

        int numApps = use.size();

        for(int r=0;r<numApps;r++){
            CodeLearnApp ap = new CodeLearnApp();
            ap.appName = use.get(r);
            ap.appTime = useTime.get(r).toString();
            codeLearnAppList.add(ap);
        }

        /*if(numApps==0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
                CodeLearnApp app = new CodeLearnApp();
                app.appName = "App " + i;
                app.appTime = "" + i;
                codeLearnAppList.add(app);
            }
        }*/
        return codeLearnAppList;

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here is my BaseAdapter:

```
public class TableViewList extends BaseAdapter {
    //allows method getDataForListView to be called from MainActivity
    MainActivity help = new MainActivity();

    List<CodeLearnApp> codeLearnAppsList = help.getDataForListView();


    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return codeLearnAppsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CodeLearnApp getItem(int arg0) {
        return codeLearnAppsList.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    /*Dont use ListViewWithBaseAdapte, use
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
}*/

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2){

        if(arg1==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(arg2.getContext());
            arg1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview_1, arg2,false);
        }

        TextView appName = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView appTime = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        CodeLearnApp appp = codeLearnAppsList.get(arg0);

        appName.setText(appp.appName);
        appTime.setText(appp.appTime);


        return arg1;
    }
}
```

Additional class used:

```
public class CodeLearnApp {

    String appName;
    String appTime;

}
```

Here is my main xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/showData"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

ListView xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:text="CodeLearn Chapter 1"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Description" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: seriously: `MainActivity help = new MainActivity();

    List<CodeLearnApp> codeLearnAppsList = help.getDataForListView();` please learn java basics first(to get why `codeLearnAppsList ` is empty) then basics of android's Activity life cycle (to get why you should never use new operator on Activity derived classes)...

Comment: I'm trying to learn as I go, sorry if I offended you

Comment: hmmm you can't just let me know how to fix my code but instead you try to belittle me.  Your comment is seriously flawed as it does't help me at all.  My code all works fine, though it may not be optimal.  I'm not submitting this anywhere I'm just trying to play around and learn with it.

Comment: ... the whole `while (i < use.size()) { ...(use.get(i)).equals(separated[2])) ... }` isn't it just ArrayList.indexOf or maybe contains? ... so `spot = use.indexOf(separated[2])` should be do the thing (i could add such comments to almost every line of this code ... but i'm not a personal teacher)